# how to add custom title on a google maps API marker?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, label, markers

I'm trying to add a title to a marker, in the same way that maps.google adds a title to their markers as described below, "Yosemite Lodge at the Falls"

[image: maps.google.com marker labeling]

I've been searching the maps API for information on how to do it, I tried adding 'labels' and 'title' to the new Marker object but none of those work. there isn't any other informations on the maps API on how to accomplish this

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3],
      text: 'australia',
});
```

Comment: It isn't supported by the native API.  [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/examples.html) is probably the closest you will come with a third party library, you can style the "label" div.  Or you might try [MapLabel](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label)

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you could register the location with Google and it will eventually appear natively in the map.

Comment: try using `label`, `title` is for roll-over text, and there's no `text` attribute based on the [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker) resource. `text` is part of the MarkerLabel resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'Geocodezip' mentioned, google does not share the technology to add labels on their markers. You'll have to add your own.
[markerwithlabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/examples.html) the 'basic.html' example here solved my problem. it allows you to add markers 
I edited the code a bit to be able to add more than one marker/label pairs

```
  var image = {
    url: './customMarker.jpg',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(100, 100),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };

var NewLabels=[

['Test2', 34.03, -118.235],
['Test1', 35.03, -117.235],
['Test2', 36.03, -116.235],
['Test3', 37.03, -115.235],
['Test4', 38.03, -114.235],

];

  for (var i = 0; i < NewLabels.length; i++) {
         var title = NewLabels[i][0];
         var title = new MapLabel({
          text: NewLabels[i][0],
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(NewLabels[i][1], NewLabels[i][2]),
          map: map,
          fontSize: 20,
          align: 'right'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, icon: image,});
        marker.bindTo('map', title);
        marker.bindTo('position', title);
        marker.setDraggable(true);
};
```